# Order of bindings in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, converters

I am facing this issue regarding data binding and binding in a converter while developing a Windows Phone 8 app.

I am trying to send the button to a converter so I can access all of its properties using the following code

```
<Button Content="{Binding OwnBoard, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource BoardToBackConv}}" />
```

When I hit the break point in the converter I have the button as the binding object, but the Content property of the control is Null. **I need to access the object stored in the Content property.**

As far as I know, because of the order of the bindings, the Content property should already contain a value.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: So if I understand your question, you are changing the background based on the Content?

Comment: @AlastairPitts Yes. This is what I want to do. Why I need the content is because I want to do this for a matrix (array of arrays) of elements. Bind to a matrix and use the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties to access the elements in the matrix so I can define the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to understand why what I want to do is not going to work.
Keeping it short, the converter is executed during the InitializeComponent() call, and at that time the other binding was not done, because there is not DataContext for the view yet.